# how to retreive record id through SOQL in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id

In triggers if i want to update a particular field then I need  to retrieve the id of particular record and  update.

I am bit confused how to get the record id of particular record in triggers whats the syntax we need to use  and if we are using SOQL in triggers how to get id of the record.

```
trigger insertcontact on account (afterinsert) {
    list<contact>csc=newcontact<contact>();
    for(Account a:trigger.new) {
        if(a.type=='other') {
            contact.add(newcontact(lastname=a.name,mailingcity=a.billing‌​city, accountid=a.id));
            insertcontacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your trigger code, the correct way of writing trigger as follows:

```
trigger insertcontact on account (after insert) 
{ 
    List<Contact> csc = new List<Contact>(); 

    for(Account a:trigger.new) 
    { 
        if(a.type=='other') 
        { 
            csc.add(new Contact(lastname=a.name,mailingcity=a.billing‌​city, accountid=a.id));
        } 
    }
    insert csc; 
}
```

Though this can be achievable by Process Builder.

Comment: yes its working perfectly but my question is why we need to take Account id=a.id

Comment: @khaleelmohammed - You don't unless you want to relate the contact to the account. Keep in mind if you do not relate a contact to an account then generally only the owner of the contact can see it.

Comment: thanks Eric  and my question as new to development i dint understand the syntax of id

Comment: Mark this as answer if it solved your problem. Will help other folks if they are looking to find solution to similar problems

Comment: @khaleelmohammed - It uniquely identifies a record. If pointing to another record it is a foreign key.